# When i try to print two documents or more using window.print() only the first displays the content

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, printing

I have a link button "Print" 
Print

When I open the first tab of printing, it shows me all the values I want.
[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSuif.png)

At the same, I open another tab in Chrome, and click the button Print and it doesn't show me the data.

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od6GL.png)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysZSJ.png)

[Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8N9f.png)

[Css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoVSZ.png)

Comment: Please provide the relevant code. With only a screenshot, we have not a single way to see how the printing is coded and hence, cannot help you solve the issue.

Comment: I upload three more images of some parts of HTML, Javascript and CSS. Tell me if you need more, is the first time i post a question here, i dont know very well how to do it correclty :)